# ajax post data in django1.5 ListView

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

So, I have a small blog app(django newbie here) with blog articles, and I am looking to include a "rating" to each of these items (similar to up/down on stackoflow). So, what I have is a ajax based GET in a ListView - but I now realize I need POST to "modify" this ratings data. I have been looking to post data from a django ListView, but I am unable to see how this can be done.  The current GET code, which is a listview of all blog articles (paginated) looks as follows:

```
#views.py
class AwesomeDisplayListView(JSONResponseMixin,ListView):
    model = blogposts
    template_name = "awesome_list.html"
    paginate_by = '15'
    context_object_name = "searchres"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        print "this is get_context_data"
        context = super(SearchDisplayListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        q = self.request.GET.get('q')
        context['searchq'] = q
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        print "this is get_queryset"
                # get some queryset
        return queryset 

    def render_to_response(self, context):
        if self.request.is_ajax():
            obj = {'name':'ajax', 'birthday':'may'}
            return JSONResponseMixin.render_to_response(self, obj)
        else:
            return ListView.render_to_response(self, context)
```

The above code works fine to get data ("obj") into the template and I am able to render both the blogposts and the GET ajax, but, what I would like to do is post data so that:
[1] the rating is increased from its current value by 1
[2] the particular action (clicking to vote), requires login_required.

I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction to do this. I have googled the problem, and people seem to suggest combining Mixins - but, unsure if this should be the case.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't tell you how much I learned by looking at the class based view source code. Once you've seen it, it becomes very easy to modify your class object to do what you want. In your case, if you add a `post` method to your class, it will be called in the event of a post to the url mapped to the view.

```
def post( self, request, *args **kwargs ):
  # receive the post, process the rating, return your JSON response
```

**In response to your comments**

Since you're wanting users to be able to upvote/downvote from a ListView, you will need some way of identifying the post being voted on to the POST view which handles the request.

So if you were to send the id of the blogpost along with the vote, you could grab that model and update it accordingly.

assuming a model like this

```
class BlogPost( models.Model ):
  upvotes=models.IntegerField( default=0 )
  downvotes=models.IntegerField( default=0 )

  def get_score( self ):
    return self.upvotes - self.downvotes

  score=property( get_score )
```

yourtemplate.html

```
{% for post in object_list %}
 <div class="blogpost" data-pk="{{post.pk}}">
  <span class="score">{{post.score}}</span>
  <a class="upvote" href="#">Upvote</a>
  <a class="downvote" href="#">Downvote</a>
 </div>
{% endfor %}
```

yourjavascript.js

```
$('.blogpost').on( 'click', '.upvote,.downvote', function( e ){
  e.preventDefault();
  var id=$( this ).closest('.blogpost').data('pk'),
  upvote=$( this ).is('.upvote'),
  xhr=$.ajax({
    url: location.href, 
    type: 'post',
    data:{ id: id, upvote: upvote ? 1 : 0 },
    dataType: 'json'
  });
  xhr.done( function( data ){
     // successful submission
  });
});
```

views.py

```
class AwesomeDisplayListView(JSONResponseMixin,ListView):
  model = BlogPost
  template_name = "awesome_list.html"
  paginate_by = '15'
  context_object_name = "searchres" 

  def post( self, request, *args, **kwargs ):
    id=request.POST.get('id')
    upvote=int( request.POST.get('upvote') )
    blogpost=BlogPost.objects.get( pk=id )
    if upvote:
      blogpost.upvotes=blogpost.upvotes + 1
    else:
      blogpost.downvotes=blogpost.downvotes + 1
    blogpost.save()
    return http.HttpResponse( json.dumps({ 'score': blogpost.score }) )
```

To expand further on my last comment, a Rating model might make this easier.

```
class BlogPost( models.Model ):
  title=models.CharField( max_length=100 )
  def get_score( self ):
    return self.ratings.filter( up=True ).count() - self.ratings.filter( up=False ).count()

  score=property( get_score )


class Rating( models.Model ):
  blogpost=models.ForeignKey( BlogPost, related_name="ratings" )
  user=models.ForeignKey( User )
  up=models.BooleanField( default=True )

  class Meta:
    unique_together=('blogpost','user',)
```

Then in your post view

```
def post( self, request, *args, **kwargs ):
  id=request.POST.get('id')
  upvote=bool( int( request.POST.get('upvote') ) )
  blogpost=BlogPost.objects.get( pk=id )
  rating, is_new=Rating.objects.get_or_create( user=request.user, blogpost=blogpost )
  if rating.up != upvote:
    rating.up=upvote
    rating.save()
```

Comment: initially, I did think of it - but, from looking at: http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.5/django.views.generic.list/ListView/ I cannot see def post - so I was under the impression that this is not allowed in ListView. Is it not the case?

Comment: Anything is allowed. It's just a simple class. Take a look at the dispatch method. If you've created a method that matches a name in `http_method_names` it will be called.

Comment: I am still unsure how I can use post.. I dont really have a form here :( and I want to post and update via ajax.. do you have some example by any chance? Thanks again

Comment: Can you explain what your rating structure looks like. Is there a Rating model?

Comment: So, my models look like the following: http://dpaste.com/1015299/ the voteup votedown are the tables I intend to modify via the ajax post.

Comment: Will multiple people be able to rate your blog posts? I'm trying to understand why you're using TextFields and what they would llke look after a number of upvotes/downvotes.

Comment: I just had TextFields for the dev version. The idea was to use some form of Int field eventually - if this makes sense. Yes, multiple people should be able to rate the blog posts and the voteup/down simply has a number stored in them (either as string or as Int)

Comment: this is simply awesome - I am yet to try it, but iam grateful for the heads up and your snippet. I will let you know how this goes - btw: does this also take care of the csrf protection?

Comment: No. CSRF protection is not included. In fact this view might not work unless you can grab the CSRF token and include it in your ajax post. i.e. `{{csrf_token}}` in your template and `$('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val()` in your post.

Comment: Another thing to note is using this method a user could upvote/downvote a post multiple times, which I would imagine is not what you want. Perhaps creating a `Rating` model with foreign keys to BlogPost and User and only creating/updating the Rating instance.

Comment: Yes, I was going to tackle the multiple votes thing on the next step - I'd want to avoid to create anything - since some of my db is legacy db for which I use inspectdb to generate my models - Do you have a solution in mind for such a case? Thanks again for everything - you have saved me a lot of time!

Comment: I updated my response with the creation of a simple Rating model. Do you want to accomplish this without creating any new tables?

Comment: Thanks again for the explanation. Yes, ideally, I would not want to create any new tables and just work with voteup/down table.

Comment: Without creating any tables I don't know how you would persistently track whether a user has voted on a particular post before. Let me know how it works and what you come up with.

Comment: Thanks so much for all your help. I will try everything out now and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Just wanted to thank you again for your snippet above - I have now tried it with a separate Rating model and it works as expected! Sorry about the delay - I had to recreate my db (I had a legacy db originally) - and thus could do it only over a weekend. Accepted your answer.